# Form with prefilled data

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a form for a new staff to fill in. But now, I want to have a edit form which return the form that user has filled.

This is my controller:

```
    public static Result updateForm(String id) {
    Form<staffInfo> existingStaffForm = Form.form(staffInfo.class);
    staffInfo existingStaff = staffInfo.find.byId(id);
    return ok(
            views.html.update.render(existingStaffForm.fill(existingStaff))
            );
}
```

This is my scala.html:

```
@(existingStaffForm: Form[staffInfo])

@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }

@main("Employment application") {

    @form(routes.Application.newForm(), 'class -> "form-horizontal") {

        <div class = "row">
        <div class="col-md-6">@inputText(existingStaffForm("fullName"), 'size->50,'_label -> "Full name:", '_help -> "*", '_showConstraints -> false)</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">@select(
                                existingStaffForm("sex"),
                                options(Seq("Male", "Female")),
                                '_label -> "Sex:")</div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

When I run on my browser, it return error `[RuntimeException: Cannot fill a form with a null value]`.
At the controller on line -> return ok.

### UPDATE

I've found out the main problem! I have a 'Update' button on the display page for the user to click (if they want to update their info), which the button will be directed to edit form page (the code is above). Here is code for the 'Update' button:

```
<a href="/staff/:id/update"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Update"></a>
```

And my routes:

```
GET     /staff/:id/update       controllers.Application.updateForm(id:String)
```

I think, the problem is at the href tag. Can someone help how to put the link in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `existingStaff` is `null`, debug it somehow. i.e.:

```
public static Result updateForm(String id) {
    Form<staffInfo> existingStaffForm = Form.form(staffInfo.class);
    staffInfo existingStaff = staffInfo.find.byId(id);

    if (existingStaff==null) {
        return badRequest("Oooops existingStaff not found in DB... ");
    }

    return ok(
            views.html.update.render(existingStaffForm.fill(existingStaff))
            );
}
```

BTW: By the convention class name of the model should start with upper case: `StaffInfo`

Comment: Hello @biesior ! Thanks for your help! I'm actually waiting for your answer since you answered most of the probs related Play Framework :) Yeah I noted about the class name. I will change it later! :D by the way, I found out what is the main problem of my code! Pls refer to above. I updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You should generate your a href using reverse routing.

```
@routes.WhateverYourControllerIsNamed.updateForm("id")
```

see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaRouting